# Nestl Historical data are missing in yahoo finance

Tags: charts, finance, yahoo-finance, stockquotes, google-finance

I am looking for historical data of different companies. I am using Yahoo Finance to acquire data and plot them in candlestick chart using matlab software. However i have noticed that yahoo finance only provides some data. For example data from 2014-03-03 - we have every day's worth of data (2014-03-03, 2014-03-04, 2014-03-05, 2014-03-06, 2014-03-07). After 2014-03-07 it jumps to 2014-03-10 what about 2014-03-08 and 2014-03-09?

This is my sql query of Nestl:
http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=NSRGY&a=0&b=1&c=2008&d=0&e=31&n=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv

Comment: Trading doesn't happen on the weekend (Saturday, Sunday which were March 8 and March 9) and thus Friday's close Price holds until open on Monday. There should be similar jumps for other weekends.

Comment: See also [Why is the stock market closed on the weekend?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8950/why-is-the-stock-market-closed-on-the-weekend)

Answer (score 0):

There is no trading on Saturdays and Sundays (i.e. 2014-03-08 and 2014-03-09)